# MongoDB post from api endpoint buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm create a simple user creation using MongoDB with endpoints to post from.

Submitting a post of json data in Postman renders a 500 internal server error and `MongooseError: Operation users.findOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms` in terminal.

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users')
require('dotenv').config()

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
}))

// Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully")
})

// Use the user router middleware
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`)
})
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


// Require the users route
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

// Use the users router as middleware with a base URL of /api/users
app.use('/api/users', usersRouter);

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

routes/users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');

router.post('/register', userController.registerUser);

module.exports = router;
```

controllers/userController.js

```
const User = require('../models/User');

// Create user
const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name, email, password } = req.body;
        // Check if user with the provided email already exists
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (existingUser) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User with this email already exists' });
        }
        // Create new user document
        const user = new User({ name, email, password });
        await user.save();
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'User registered successfully', user });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
    }
}

module.exports = {
    registerUser
}
```

models/User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Then in Postman I'm just doing a simple post to http://localhost:3000/api/users/register

```
{
    "name": "John New",
    "email": "john.new@example.com",
    "password": "password123"
}
```

Any advice would be helpful, I feel like I'm going round in circles and missing something obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed from an oversight from following tutorials. I was foolishly running index.js and app.js when this is completely unnecessary. Only index.js needed to be ran as it's connecting to Mongo, then my endpoint need to change in postman.

Then success!